# How to make dynamic column in query in cakephp 2

Tags: cakephp

I'm having trouble with this. I got stuck for this for couple of hours. What I wanted to happen is to display date range as another column in the query. so I have this query

```
  SELECT id, created, 
    COUNT(IF(DATE(created) = "2019-02-01",1, null)) AS "2019-02-01",
    COUNT(IF(DATE(created) = "2019-02-01",2, null)) AS "2019-02-02",
    COUNT(IF(DATE(created) = "2019-02-03",1, null)) AS "2019-02-03",
    COUNT(IF(DATE(created) = "2019-02-04",1, null)) AS "2019-02-04",
    COUNT(IF(DATE(created) = "2019-02-05",1, null)) AS "2019-02-05"
    FROM logs WHERE DATE(created) = "2019-02-01" AND message= 'Login' AND username = 'aaa@example.com';
```

AND I have this result for the query above
[image: this is the reult when execute the query]

So to convert it in cakephp way this what I did

```
     $start = strtotime($start_date);
        $end = strtotime($end_date);

        $dates = [];
        for ($currentDate = $start; $currentDate <= $end;  
            $currentDate += (86400)) { 

            $Store = date('Y-m-d', $currentDate); 
            $dates[] = $Store; 
        } 

           foreach ($dates AS $d) {
               $logs = $this->Log->find("all", [

                'fields' => ['Log.id',
                    'Log.created',
                    'COUNT(IF(DATE(Log.created) = "'.$d.'",1, null)) AS "'.$d.'"'
                ],
                'conditions' => $conditions,

            ]);
```

But this code giving me a different output. It only display one date

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Log] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 46260
                    [created] => 2019-02-05 11:10:12
                )

            [0] => Array
                (
                    [2019-02-05] => 1
                )

        )
)
```

What Im expecting output is like this

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Log] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 46260
                    [created] => 2019-02-05 11:10:12
                )

            [Date] => Array
                (
                    [2019-02-01] => 4,
                    [2019-02-02] => 0,
                    [2019-02-03] => 0,
                    [2019-02-04] => 0,
                    [2019-02-05] => 0,

                )

        )
)
```

I want to know whats wrong with my work and how to make it right. Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running a new query, and overwriting the results of the previous one, each time through the `foreach` loop. What you want is to build up the list of fields in there, and then run just one query.

```
$fields = ['Log.id', 'Log.created'];
foreach ($dates AS $d) {
    $fields[] = 'COUNT(IF(DATE(Log.created) = "'.$d.'",1, null)) AS "'.$d.'"';
}
$logs = $this->Log->find("all", compact('fields', 'conditions'));
```

In fact, if you're not using that `$dates` variable anywhere else, then you can merge the two loops.

```
$fields = ['Log.id', 'Log.created'];
for ($currentDate = $start; $currentDate <= $end; $currentDate += (86400)) {
    $d = date('Y-m-d', $currentDate);
    $fields[] = 'COUNT(IF(DATE(Log.created) = "'.$d.'",1, null)) AS "'.$d.'"';
} 
$logs = $this->Log->find("all", compact('fields', 'conditions'));
```